# How to pick only specific versions to build inside my satis project?

Tags: php, composer-php, satis

I didn't know that `satis` would install all the versions of the packages inside it so basically this is my satis.json file

```
{
    "name"  :"offline-packages/satis-packages",
    "description":"Offline Packages Generator",
    "homepage": "https://localhost:3200",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/akaunting/money.git"
        },
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-confirm-email.git"
        },
        // ...  more repositories here
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/webpatser/laravel-countries.git"
        }],
    "require-all": true,
    "require-dependencies": true,
    "require-dev-dependencies": true,
    "archive": {
        "directory": "dist"
    }
}
```

But what I want is to install only specific versions based on what is higher than a specific version and not all of them before I build it with

```
php bin/satis build satis.json web/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified `require-all: true`.

If you do not want to require all, but to pick specific versions, you need to add the appropriate `require` key in your configuration.

From [the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#setup):

> If you want to cherry pick which packages you want, you can list all the packages you want to have in your satis repository inside the classic composer require key, using a "*" constraint to make sure all versions are selected, or another constraint if you want really specific versions.

The example they provide in the docs should be clear enough:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/mycompany/privaterepo" },
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "http://svn.example.org/private/repo" },
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/mycompany/privaterepo2" }
  ],
  "require": {
    "company/package": "*",
    "company/package2": "*",
    "company/package3": "2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, do you know how to specify versions only that are higher than a specific version of that module ?? for example `laravel/laravel`, or should I specify it there manually on my own..?? so that I would save time